# Multivariable piece-wise linear approximation in R?

Tags: r, approximation, interpolation

I am trying to run linear approximation on a function of 2 or 4 variables.

The approx function in R is a very nice, optimized time saver, but it only works for 1 dimension functions I think.

Anyone have any suggestions for multivariate functions?

Comment: You mean *piecewise* linear, right?  (The default linear approximation function in `R` is `lm` and it works just fine with multiple variables.)

Comment: Piecewise, yes @whuber

Comment: If it *must* be piecewise linear, then you are asking how to triangulate the explanatory variables.  Search rseek.org for "triangulation" for links to packages.  I believe they are all 2D or 3D.  With more than three variables, you should do a wider search: there exist specialized stand-alone package for higher-dimensional triangulation.  If it doesn't have to be piecewise linear, then you have a much wider array of solutions available: all kinds of splines, generalized additive models, etc.

Comment: Are you sure @whuber?  That doesn't seem to yield any promising packages.

Comment: I did the search before I posted that comment and saw a bunch listed, including [`sfdct`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sfdct/vignettes/sfdct.html), [`RTriangle`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RTriangle/versions/1.6-0.8/topics/triangulate), and [`spatstat`](https://rdrr.io/cran/spatstat/man/delaunay.html) (which is popular).